# Is there a way to metricize the notion of $C^\infty$ convergence of pointed Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

A sequence of pointed Riemannian manifolds $(M_n,p_n,g_n)$ is said to converge $C^\infty$ to pointed Riemannian manifold $(M,p,g)$ if for each positive radius $R$ there exists sequence of embeddings $f_n$ of the open ball of radius $R$ centered at $p$ into $M_n$ sending $p$ to $p_n$ and with the property that the pullback metric $f_n^*g_n$ converges $C^\infty$ (in any local chart) to the metric $g$.

There are several families of manifolds which are known to be compact with respect to this notion of convergence in the sense that any sequence has a converging subsequence.  For example in Petersen's book `Riemannian Geometry' chapter 10 is dedicated to proving compactness of manifolds which can be covered by certain controlled types of atlas'.

For the notion of pointed Gromov-Hausdorff convergence we have something better, the Gromov-Hausdorff metric, which turns these `sequentially compact' sets of pointed manifolds into bonna fide compact metric spaces.

Hence my question:  **Is there a way to metricize (even topologize) the notion of $C^\infty$ convergence of pointed Riemannian manifolds?**

Comment: As far as I know the fact that isometry types of compact metric spaces with GH distance form a metric space does not have any applications. It is merely a convinient language to speak of sequential GH convergence; it is the sequential convergence that matters. The same is true for smooth pointed convergence. I suppose one could make a definition by comparing the metrics on $n$-balls about base point $p_n$ and adding weights that go to zero fast enough, namely look at $d(g_1, g_2)=\sum_n 2^{-n} d_n(g_1, g_2)$
where $d_n(g_1, g_2)$ is a smooth distance between the two metrics on
the $n$-ball.

Comment: @Igor: The application I have in mind involves considering random manifolds.  Almost any serious work with probability measures (e.g. if one needs weak convergence, conditional measures, etc) requires a Polish space.

Comment: @Igor: Also, I believe your  answer is circular since you define $d_n$ as the "smooth distance" between two metrics which are defined on different manifolds.  How to define this "smooth distance" is more or less the question.

Comment: Oh, I thought "pointed" is the key, to deal with noncompact manifolds. There are various ways to define what you want, see http://library.msri.org/books/Book30/files/PS.old/petersen.ps


Comment: Maybe it doesn't not give "what you want" but it is a starting point.

Comment: @Igor: Cool, thanks for the link.  I've been looking at Petersen's book, but I didn't know about this survey.